# PyQt5: Antialising fails for masked QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Consider the following minimal example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class FooPushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)

        self.setMask(QtGui.QRegion(self.rect(), QtGui.QRegion.Ellipse))

    def paintEvent(self, event: QtGui.QPaintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        pen = QtCore.Qt.NoPen
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)

        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)

        painter.drawEllipse(self.rect())

        painter.end()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        graphicsScene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        graphicsScene.addWidget(FooPushButton())

        graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        graphicsView.setScene(graphicsScene)

        self.setCentralWidget(graphicsView)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This renders a round `QPushButton` into a `QGraphicsScene`, However,
the antialiasing render hint is not respected. Removing the call to `setMask` causes antialiasing to work again. I imagine this is because antialiasing is not actually applied to the visible button border resulting from the masking operation.

How can I work around this?

Comment: As a side note one (rather unsatisfactory) possibility I've come up with is to use e.g. `painter.drawEllipse(self.rect().marginsRemoved(QtCore.QMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)))` but I'd rather do without the extra margin.

Comment: the problem is not antialiasing, the problem is setMask() and that effect has always existed.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. So you're saying this is unavoidable?

Comment: Yes, that's what I say